# Stubbed method returns nil inside a before_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, rspec, stubbing

I'm in a dead end testing a before_create callback in my models.

My spec

```
# The spec
let(:stamp){ mock_model(CompanyStamp) }
let(:signature){ mock_model(CompanyHandwrittenSignature) }
let(:account) { mock_model(Account, :company_handwritten_signature => signature, :company_stamp => stamp) }
it "should have signature if the account has signature" do
  subject.stub :account => account
  subject.stub :save => true
  subject.company_handwritten_signature.should == signature
end
```

Here is my model's code

```
# the model's code
before_create do |element|
  puts "element.account ===> #{element.account.inspect}"  # element has no account! wtf!?
  element.company_handwritten_signature ||= element.account.company_handwritten_signature
  element.company_stamp ||= element.account.company_stamp
  true
end
```

The before_filter method is being called, but inside that callback, the stubbing of the account method does not seems to work. 
I've tested

```
subject.account = account
```

with identical result. What's going on?

By the way, i'm using rails 2.3 and rspec-rails 1.3.4

Answer (score 0):

The way you are stubbing methods doesn't look right. I've always used something along the lines of:

```
subject.stub(:method).and_return(value)
```

Have you tried this format? Also, why are you stubbing save? It seems like that might affect some expected ActiveRecord behavior.

```
let(:stamp){ mock_model(CompanyStamp) }
let(:signature){ mock_model(CompanyHandwrittenSignature) }
let(:account) { mock_model(Account, :company_handwritten_signature => signature, :company_stamp => stamp) }
it "should have signature if the account has signature" do
  subject.stub(:account).and_return(account)
  subject.stub(:save).and_return(true)
  subject.company_handwritten_signature.should == signature
end
```

Comment: subject.stub(:method).and_return(value) and subject.stub :account => account are the same. It is just syntax sugar, but i've used the long syntax with same result.
If a realy call save i have the account, so there is some unexpected active_record behavior. When i save i get a sql error instead: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in 'TransportDocument INSTANCE METHODS STAMP AND SIGNATURE should have signature if the account has signature'
Mysql::Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails